# iOS app distribution without AppStore

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution

I need to publish my iOS app without using the AppStore to my final users, so I'm minding how StackExchange doing for its app: https://mobile.stackexchange.com/ios

I found this http://gknops.github.io/adHocGenerate/ and I think is the correct way.

I know that I'll miss all AppStore related features and I have to handle the app upgrade "manually", but is not a problem. What are other side effects/limits if any?

Can I use this way for production publishing without problems? Do I need to register the clients UDID to let them install the app? I can't know them...

If this is not appropriate for SO please guide me to another SE site.

Comment: regular ad-hoc profile needs to manually add the devices you want your app to install to. You can use an enterprise ad-hoc (if you purchase an enterprise account, but apple will ask you for a DUNs number, so you need a company), enterprise ad-hoc profiles don't have to add the devices where it will install. Or you can try Xcode 7 GM, I heard that you can install apps on devices without a developer certificate. Anyway, I think this question is not suitable for StackOverflow

Comment: Maybe better suited for [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @jcesarmobile thanks, I have an enterprise account, it allows unlimited download without any registration of UDID's? Is there a similar channel for APK's too, without check "Unknown sources" on Android?

Comment: yeah, if you have an enterprise account anyone can install the app, but according to the "Terms and conditions" you signed, only people who work on your enterprise should install it. Not sure about APK's, try to distribute it signed

Comment: @jcesarmobile but I need my end users (not of my organization) to not install a certificate because is not possibile :-( do you handle a similar situation?

Comment: the users technically can install your app if it's signed with an enterprise certificate, *but legally shouldn't*.

Comment: @jcesarmobile ok thanks for the clarification, if you want you can add the previous comments as an answer